# Never notify HDN_TRACK message of CListCtrl's CHeaderCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I want to catch `HDN_TRACK` message from listCtrl's header, but it's never notified.

I tested `HDN_BEGINTRACK` and `HDN_ENDTRACK`, and these are working well.

I also changed the Control Id of message map to `IDC_TEST_LIST` and `0`, there was no difference - it is still not working.

I searched many forums, but I couldn't find any solution.

Here's my test code.

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgTest, CDialogEx)
    //ON_NOTIFY(HDN_BEGINTRACK, 0, &CDlgTest::OnTrackListTest) // WORKING!!
    //ON_NOTIFY(HDN_ENDTRACK, 0, &CDlgTest::OnTrackListTest) // WORKING!!
    //ON_NOTIFY(HDN_TRACK, IDC_TEST_LIST, &CDlgTest::OnTrackListTest) // NOT WORKING
    ON_NOTIFY(HDN_TRACK, 0, &CDlgTest::OnTrackListTest)   // NOT WORKING
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CDlgTest::OnTrackListLog(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER phdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHEADER>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    AfxMessageBox(L"Hello!!!");     // >>>>>>>>>>> NOT showing up

    *pResult = 0;
}


class CDlgTest : public CDialogEx {
    
public:
    afx_msg void OnTrackListLog(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
}
```

I append some forums that I visited:

- https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?314900-HOW-detect-the-column-is-resize-in-CListCtrl
- http://rsdn.org/forum/mfc/1081554.all

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd behavior with header control, it's described in
[HDN_TRACK and HDS_FULLDRAG](https://thomasfreudenberg.com/archive/2004/03/14/hdn-track-and-hds-fulldrag/) also posted by @Constantine

You have to remove `HDS_FULLDRAG` style from header control in `OnInitDialog`:

```
m_list.GetHeaderCtrl()->ModifyStyle(HDS_FULLDRAG, 0);
```

Then you should receive `HDN_TRACK` message

```
void CDlgTest::OnTrack(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    TRACE(L"OnTrack\n");
    *pResult = 0;
}

ON_NOTIFY(HDN_TRACK, 0, OnTrack)
```

But now you don't have `HDS_FULLDRAG` style! If `HDS_FULLDRAG` flag is required, then don't change in `OnInitDialog`. Instead, you can enable/disable `HDS_FULLDRAG` in response to `HDN_BEGINTRACK/HDN_ENDTRACK`

Answer (score 2):

First try `HDN_TRACKA` or `HDN_TRACKW` instead of `HDN_TRACK` and see if these work. Normally `HDN_TRACK` is defined correctly as either of the two according to your project settings, but better try both.

Also, searched a little bit on the i-net and [**found**](https://thomasfreudenberg.com/archive/2004/03/14/hdn-track-and-hds-fulldrag/) that a list-control with the `HDS_FULLDRAG` style set sends the `HDN_ITEMCHANGING`rather than the `HDN_TRACK` notification. The article dates back to 2004!...

So you can try either removing that style, if this is OK to you, or capturing the `HDN_ITEMCHANGING` notification instead. The style can be set or removed by changing the initial creation style-flags if it created programmatically, by changing the resource file (or using the property editor) if it is created using a dialog resource, or by calling `GetWindowLong()`/`SetWindowLong()` after it is created.