# How to repaint a TListView column while resizing the column?

Tags: delphi, winapi, tlistview, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I need to repaint a whole `TListView` column while resizing the column. The ListView items and subitems are being displayed with `ListView.OwnerDraw`.

So I subclassed the ListView to be notified when the column resizes:

```
TListView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView)
  private
    FHeaderHandle: HWND;
    procedure WMNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotify); message WM_NOTIFY;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
...

procedure TListView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  FHeaderHandle := ListView_GetHeader(Handle);
end;

procedure TListView.WMNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotify);
begin
  if (AMessage.NMHdr.hwndFrom = FHeaderHandle) and ((AMessage.NMHdr.code = HDN_ENDTRACK) or (AMessage.NMHdr.code = HDN_TRACK)) then
  begin
    TMessage(AMessage).Result := 0;
    InvalidateRect(FHeaderHandle, nil, true);
    CodeSite.Send('TListView.WMNotify: HDN_ENDTRACK');
  end
  else  
    inherited;
end;
```

Unfortunately, it reacts only at the END of column resizing, and not WHILE resizing the column! Also, the column is not repainted!

Comment: Do you want to repaint only the header at the top of the column (like the text "Description") or do you want to repaint the entire column (like 100 rows)?

Comment: Repaint the entire column rows. I.e., doing the same as in `OnDrawItem`.

Comment: "*Repaint the entire column rows*" - invalidating just a header item won't invalidate the whole column.  You will have to do that separately by using the ListView's HWND with `InvalidateRect()`, specifying the rect of the column (which you will have to calculate manually using the position and width of the header item and the height of the ListView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `HDN_TRACK` not being delivered [is well known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68616247/never-notify-hdn-track-message-of-clistctrls-cheaderctrl). A solution is to look for `HDN_ITEMCHANGING` instead.

Regarding the repainting issue, notice that you do

```pascal
InvalidateRect(FHeaderHandle, nil, true);
```

This requests a repaint of the *list view header*. The header is a separate window, a [header control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/header-controls), which occupies the top row of your list view and contains only the column captions.

You want to invalidate not the header, but the actual column in the list view.

Just invalidate the entire list view.

Comment: "*Just invalidate the entire list view*" - or, at least, just the rectangle of the desired column.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Of course. But it is probably easier to be lazy and simply redraw the whole thing.

Comment: Replacing `HDN_TRACK` with `HDN_ITEMCHANGING` does work: Now it reacts WHILE resizing the column. However, even if I invalidate the whole ListView, the column's SubItems are not moved together with the column header:  https://www.screencast.com/t/eDH03ppli

Comment: @user1580348: That probably depends on how exactly you are drawing the items and subitems (which I don't know!). In any case, I think that's a different question.

Comment: (You did replace `InvalidateRect(FHeaderHandle, nil, true);` with `Invalidate;`, right?)

Comment: This is how I am drawing the Items and SubItems in `OnDrawItem`: https://www.screencast.com/t/RO7sOc4pbZ2

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if i = 0 then SS := Item.Caption else SS := Item.SubItems[i - 1];`? Also, why do you duplicate `SS` in `SS := #32 + SS`? If a column's value is "Dog", that will write "Dog Dog" there. This code looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes, I did replace `InvalidateRect(FHeaderHandle, nil, true);` with `Invalidate;`

Comment: Yes, even if I use `SS := Item.SubItems[i - 1];` to draw the SubItem, the result is the same, because I have only 1 SubItem column. The text drawing in `OnDrawItem` does work as the SubItems are displayed correctly. - What I need is to apply the `OnDrawItem` procedure.

Comment: @user1580348: It works perfectly on my system with https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDTbg.png Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExNPl.gif (Sorry, forgot to turn on DoubleBuffered there.)

Comment: (Invalidating the list view *will* cause your `OnDrawItem` to be called if `OwnerDraw = True`.)

Comment: Solved: The first column was set to `AutoSize`! Now, after having switched OFF `AutoSize` for the first column, it works!

Comment: @user1580348: Great!

Comment: But now, after having `AutoSize` switched off, there is another bad side effect: `RowSelect` does not work anymore and the Item Captions have an Ellipsis at the end that shortens the caption!

Comment: @user1580348: Well, since the list view is owner drawn, it is *you* who are doing the painting. So if you want to highlight a row, you have to paint it blue (or whatever) yourself. If you don't want ellipses, don't pass the `tfEndEllipsis` flag. I don't think this has anything to do with `AutoSize`.

Comment: It DOES have to do with `AutoSize`, because when I turn 'AutoSize' OFF then all these bad things happen. And I HAVE removed the `tfEndEllipsis ` flag.

Comment: If you create a new VCL app, drop a TListView on it, set it to report mode, enable double buffering, create two columns, add the interceptor class, set it to owner draw, and use my handler above, I am pretty sure it will work. You may have forgotten some property you have altered or maybe you have other event handlers or other code interfering.

Comment: And if you get ellipses in your owner-drawn cells without specifying `tfEndEllipsis`, something is very wrong. Are you sure your code is called at all? Try to draw the text `'Cats are cute'` instead of the cell's text just to see that it is actually your code that is drawing the cells!

Comment: I have now solved the problem by intelligently integrating the different drawing methods in OnDrawItem, which were previously stacked on each other. It took a lot of thinking, but it worked out in the end. It is too complex to explain here.